# windows10のタスクバーをwindowsボタンを押した時だけ表示させたい。

Tags: windows-10

windows10のタスクバーをwindowsボタンを押した時だけ表示させたい。

現在、「デスクトップモードでタスクバーを自動的に隠す」をオンにしています。
しかし、カーソルを下の方へ持っていくと、毎回タスクバーが表示されたり、消えたりします。

これをwindowsボタンを押した時のみ、タスクバーを表示させたいのです。どうすればよいのでしょうか。

ご回答お待ちしております。
よろしくお願いします。

追伸
すみません、stack overflowにおいて、するべき質問ではありませんでした。
近日中に削除します。

Comment: takaponさん、こちらのご質問は、プログラミングというよりかWindowsにおけるUIの使い方に関するものに近いのでクローズされたのだと思います。ただ、クローズされたからといって手動で削除なさる必要は必ずしもありません :)　今回は回答が集まっておりますし、誰かの役に立つかもしれないからです。話題の範囲については次回以降気をつけて頂ければ大丈夫です！　クローズされた質問は、もし必要なければシステムによって自動削除されますのでご安心ください。今回はご質問ありがとうございました <(_ _)>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ウェブ検索してみると「Taskbar Disabler」というアプリが見つかりましたが、Windows 7向けとなっているのでWindows 10でも動作するのかまでは確認できていません。

[Windowsのタスクバーを一時的に消す「Taskbar Disabler」](https://forest.watch.impress.co.jp/docs/serial/okiniiri/435742.html)